# My background Image will not show up

Tags: css

I think it might be a minor syntax error somewhere but as far as I can tell the code looks fine. I have the image and stylesheet set in their own folders within the parent; I have taken into account that the image needs to be fetched with from the parent folder so i have it set as so: "...\images(imagename).jpg"; but even with that it is not working here is an example of my code below.

```css
body {
  background-image: url('...\images\swirl.png');
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

I have also checked with images off the web, those seem to work fine, but i'd rather not try to fetch an image every time i use my page.

Comment: use this `background-image: url('..\images\swirl.png');`

Comment: In case you are going crazy looking for the difference between your code and Saurabh's, you have an extra '.' in your relative path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Following.

**EDIT**

```
body {
  background-image: url('../images/swirl.png');
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: no luck, i don't believe that the extra periods make a difference... certainly didnt change anything for me.

Comment: @TylerLesterAshbrook i have edit my answer pls check again.

Comment: So it was multiple issues but the back slash seem to do the trick... i had tried reversing before but that was before i had them in separate folders, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your image is rightly fetched from 'image' folder path, then try below style:

```
body {
  background-image: url('./images/swirl.png');
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: again, no luck... the number of periods makes no difference whatsoever.